# Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_PERMISSION_MODEL_DOWNGRADE]

Tags: android, cordova, command, cordova-cli

I entered the command below in the CMD and the command returned the error below the command.

**Command:**

```
phonegap run android --verbose --stacktrace
```

**Error:**

> ERROR: Failed to launch application on device:
>
> ERROR: Failed to install apk to device:    pkg: /data/local/tmp/MainActivity-debug.apk
>
> Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_PERMISSION_MODEL_DOWNGRADE]

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The problem there, is that you are attempting to install a version of your APK that is LESS than what is already on your device.

Uninstalling will certainly fix that problem for you.

ADB allows more flexibility `adb install -r -d <apk path>`, but I am not sure that Phonegap has that functionality.

```
adb install [-lrtsdg] <file>
   - push this package file to the device and install it
     (-l: forward lock application)
     (-r: replace existing application)
     (-t: allow test packages)
     (-s: install application on sdcard)
     (-d: allow version code downgrade)
     (-g: grant all runtime permissions)
```

**Update:**

It turns out that was not the correct error message for downgrading the App version. Infact, it is something completely separate. I [found this link](https://plus.google.com/+RoySolberg/posts/Lfj9NRoaz2V) that accurately explains the situation:

> tl;dr You can't fool the new Android 6 permissions model by first
>   publishing an APK with targetSdk 23 which will grant all permissions
>   runtime and then publishing a new version with targetSdk 22 or less.
>   You'll get an INSTALL_FAILED_PERMISSION_MODEL_DOWNGRADE error.
>
> I was working on an app with targetSdk 23 (Android 6 Marshmallow) when
>   it hit me that it possibly could be a security issue with the new
>   Android permission model. Android 6 devices approves all permission on
>   install time and then the user has to approve them whenever the app
>   asks for the permission. What if the user installed the app - auto
>   granting all permissions - and then it didn't ask for using them, and
>   then afterwards the app was updated with the same permissions, but
>   with a lower targetSdk?
>
> I spent a couple minutes creating an app that targeted SDK level 23
>   and added a fine location permission (ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION). Then I
>   installed and ran the app. The app didn't ask for permission to access
>   the location manager. Then I set the SDK level to 22 and tried to
>   install the app. Luckily it wasn't able to install. I got an error
>   saying Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_PERMISSION_MODEL_DOWNGRADE].

Comment: Where does the **-r** stand for? I can't find it in [the android debug bridge documentation of developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html). Could you also say what you mean with 'version'. It's a little vague.

Comment: I updated my question to reflex the option meaning. By version I mean your App version. If you have App version 3 installed, and attempt to install App version 2. It will not allow it without hte degradation flag.

Comment: I tested your theory. I changed my app version from 2 to 1 and I got a different error: `[INSTALL_FAILED_VERSION_DOWNGRADE]` so I am confused. Does this error mean the same as the one I had before: `[INSTALL_FAILED_PERMISSION_MODEL_DOWNGRADE]`? I am curious what the difference is between those errors.

Comment: It looks like I was wrong. The error message is quite similar. I found the real reason though. Ill edit my answer.

Comment: The -d option only works for debuggable apks. From adb -help: "-d: allow version code downgrade (debuggable packages only)"

Comment: Since the first section about `INSTALL_FAILED_VERSION_DOWNGRADE` is misleading to this issue, would you edit and restructure the answer so that the second section about `INSTALL_FAILED_PERMISSION_MODEL_DOWNGRADE` is explained first, then perhaps additionally mentioning "not to be confused with `INSTALL_FAILED_VERSION_DOWNGRADE` when [...]"

Answer (score 10):

**Solution:**

I managed to get rid of the error by uninstalling my app from my device.

**Cause:**

What probably caused the error is that I updated my Android SDK with [SDK Manager](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/sdk-manager.html).

Answer (score 0):

I got this error in VS2015 using TACO and debugging for Android using a particular emulator profile: VS Emulator 10.1" Marshmallow (6.0.0) XHDPI Tablet.  The project I was working on was installed as an app on that particular profile because I had been using it for debugging.  I solved the problem by uninstalling and reinstalling that particular profile:  Tools -> Visual Studio Emulator for Android -> Uninstall profile.  The reinstalled profile no longer contained my app and the error went away.  It's the VS Emulator equivalent of uninstalling the app from a remote device, I guess.